# Change Icon GMMaker

Tags: gmlib

How do I change the icon using the Imagelist?

This works very well

```
GMMarker1.Items[markers].Icon := 'C:\Test\icon01.png';
```

But this don't work

```
imagelist.GetBitmap(1, GMMarker1.Items[markers].Icon);
```

Thanks

Comment: must be a physical file on your PC or on the internet

Comment: OK, understand. Thanks